# Add layer to GeoServer from one PostGIS table

Tags: postgis, geoserver, geonode

I have a Geonode/Geoserver application with a lot of base layers added to it. I have also developed a Django App plugged into Geonode that lets a user upload shapefiles. These shapefiles are converted using shp2pgsql and stored in a `uploads` PostGIS table, with each upload having a unique `id` key.

Once a user uploads a shapefile, the app runs SQL queries to compare (check for overlapping areas) the uploaded shapefile with existing base layers and results are stored in a database table. So far, this has been done.

But now, I need to show the upload shapefile on top of existing base layers in a map viewer (Geonode). Wondering what would be the best approach.

Do I have to add the uploaded shapefiles to GeoServer? Or can I set the `uploads` table as a PostGIS datastore in GeoServer and have it create layers from each row?

Comment: can you expand on what you mean by you store the new layer in a row of the uploads table. Usually a shapefile contains more than one feature.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.